# Azure DevOps IIS Deploy Pipelines - where do variable values source from in templates?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I oversee some teams, and one team has an Azure DevOps pipeline leveraging the YAML pipeline setup. Unfortunately, due to Covid-19, we have had to release a lot of staff, including the entire DevOps team. That has left my team with no DevOps knowledge and an established YAML pipeline that we're struggling to get acquainted with.

So far, we've make progress and have learned a lot. However, while trying to troubleshoot an IIS web site deployment task, we have had some trouble figuring out where some of the parameters passed to each stage are sourced from.

For example, a snippet from a template:

```
      - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
        displayName: 'Create Or Update IIS Website'
        inputs:
          EnableIIS: true
          WebsiteName: ${{ parameters.WebsiteName }}
          WebsitePhysicalPath: ${{ parameters.WebsitePhysicalPath }}
          AddBinding: ${{ parameters.AddWebsiteBinding }}
          **Bindings: ${{ parameters.WebsiteBindings }}**
          CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: ${{ parameters.CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite }}
          AppPoolNameForWebsite: ${{ parameters.WebsiteName }}
          DotNetVersionForWebsite: ${{ parameters.DotNetVersionForWebsite }}
          PipeLineModeForWebsite: ${{ parameters.PipeLineModeForWebsite }}
          AppPoolIdentityForWebsite: ${{ parameters.AppPoolIdentityForWebsite }}
          AppPoolUsernameForWebsite: ${{ parameters.AppPoolUsernameForWebsite }}
```

"WebsiteBindings" is one that we're interested in ... and I can work back to where the template is being used, and see this:

WebsiteBindings: '$(DevOps:IISWebsiteBindings)'

Problem is - I want to see what is being passed in here, and I cannot seem to figure out where the above value comes from. I am sure the answer is simple, but none of us have any Azzure DevOps experience, and we're kind of stuck on this simple problem. Is there anything in the above syntax that can clue me in as to where the values are located?

Other areas in the pipeline are referencing Azure AppConfig Key/Value storage for config transforms, and there are some pipeline variables set, but none line up with any of the values I am looking for.

Can anyone provide any insight here? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is - I want to see what is being passed in here, and I cannot
>   seem to figure out where the above value comes from.

You can add a [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) task and output these variables through `Write-Host` to see what is passed here . For example : `Write-Host "$(parameters.WebsiteBindings)"`

According to the syntax of `${{ parameters.WebsiteBindings }}`, I speculate that this variable comes from the template parameters.

In a pipeline, [template expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#template-expression-syntax) variables (`${{ variables.var }}`) get processed at compile time, before runtime starts. You can use template expression syntax to expand both [template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) and variables . Template expressions are designed for reusing parts of YAML as templates.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the Powershell task - that is helpful. Any idea where the syntax "$(DevOps:IISWebsiteBindings)" pulls values from?

Comment: `DevOps:IISWebsiteBindings`should not be a [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), this should be a custom variable.  You need to find the variable named `DevOps:IISWebsiteBindings` .

Comment: That is my problem - I can't find it anywhere. Maybe I just don't know where to look.

Comment: You can search it in yaml pipeline script , template yaml ,variable group , script in pipeline and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LApt7.png)(click [Triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjxP.png) to jump to this page).You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) about define variable and try to list all of the variables in your pipeline with the az pipelines variable list command.